# Upgrading GeoServer version running with Jetty

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, jetty

I have a GeoServer install (2.1.3) running with Jetty that I need to update to the latest release, but I can't lose any of the residing data files and layers configuration.

Can you help to obtain this (on an Ubuntu 10.04LTS VM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- copy your data directory (.../data/*) somewhere safe.
- Download and
  install the latest version of GeoServer.
- create an environment
  variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=.../someplace/safe/geoserver_data (or
  wherever you stashed your data)
- start up the new version of
  GeoServer.

[image]

Click on Server Status to check that you have changed your data directory.